# Inspiration behind substitution of main variable in Cardano's solution

Tags: polynomials, cubics

Suppose the solutions to a general cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ are to be found. Then according to Cardano's method, First a variable substitution must be carried on to convert the general cubic to depressed cubic.
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0\rightarrow t^3+pt+q=0\ \text{where $t=x-\frac{b}{3a}$}$$
This seems pretty clear but what happens next is not so obvious for me.

Now we take $t=u+v$ to get $u^3+v^3+(3uv+p)(u+v)+q=0$. Assuming $3uv+p=0$, we get the system
$$u^3+v^3=-q$$ $$uv=\frac{-p}{3}$$. Using Vieta's formula, the quadratic equation with $u^3$ and $v^3$ as roots is $$x^2+qx-\frac{p^3}{27}=0$$
Now the roots for quadratic can be found by analysing the discriminant.

My doubt is that what was the inspiration behind assuming $3uv+p=0$, except helping to form the quadratic equation.

*Please help*

***THANKS***

Comment: Ambiguous and possibly controversial question.  My **blind instinct** is that mathematicians stumbled around for centuries going down blind alleys, and then somebody got lucky.  Like looking for oil, accidentally striking it rich and then being asked how you knew there was oil there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a geometric picture behind this. The expression $(u+v)^3$ can be visualized as a cube subdivided into eight rectangular solids of sides $u\times u\times u$, $u\times u\times v$ (permuted three ways), $u\times v\times v$ (permuted three ways), and $v\times v\times v$. As an alternative, however, it can be understood as subdivided into five rectangular solids of sides $u\times u\times u$, $t\times u\times v$ (cyclically permuted three ways), and $v\times v\times v$.

[image]

If $p$ and $q$ are negative, the equation $t^3+pt=-q$ can be understood geometrically as saying that if from a cube of side $t$ a rectangular solid of length $t$ and cross-sectional area $-p$ is removed, or three rectangular solids of length $t$ and cross-sectional area $-\frac{p}{3}$ are removed, then the remaining volume is $-q$. If we arrange for the cross-sectional area $-\frac{p}{3}$ to be that of a $u\times v$ rectangle, then the remaining volume will consist of a cube of side $u$ and a cube of side $v$. Hence we have
$$
v=-\frac{p}{3u},\quad u^3+v^3=-q,
$$
which is quadratic in $u^3$.

This doesn't come completely out of the blue: at the point in time when Tartaglia solved the depressed cubic, there was a 3500 year history of solving quadratics using an analogous 2-dimensional geometric picture. The ancient Mesopotamians, for example, solved, in essence, the problem of finding $t$ given that $t(t+a)=b$. They did this by arranging a square of side $t$, a square of side $\frac{a}{2}$, and rectangles of dimensions $t\times\frac{a}{2}$ and $\frac{a}{2}\times t$ into a square of side $t+\frac{a}{2}$, which must then have area $b+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$. From $\left(t+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2=b+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2$, one can compute $t+\frac{a}{2}$ and hence $t$. Although the Mesopotamian algorithms were described in words only, accompanied neither by equations nor by geometric diagrams, a careful [analysis](https://www.mprl-series.mpg.de/textbooks/2/4/index.html) by Jens Høyrup of the geometric terminology used provides convincing evidence that this was how they understood their procedures. Closer to the time of Tartaglia, al-Khwarizmi solved quadratics by methods based on a similar geometric picture.

Answer (score 1):

One source of inspiration may have been looking at the binomial expansion of $(u+v)^3$ and mapping it to the cubic $t^3 + pt +q = 0$.

$$\begin{align*}(u+v)^3 &= u^3 +3 u^2v +3uv^2+v^3 \\
\\
&= u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v) \\
\\
(u+v)^3 - 3uv(u+v)-(u^3+v^3)&= 0\\
\end{align*}$$

Substituting $t =u+v$ yields

$$t^3-3uvt-(u^3+v^3) =0$$

Which forces the equalities
$$ p = -3uv$$
$$q= -(u^3+v^3)$$
to complete the mapping of the depressed cubic equation to the equation for the cube of a binomial.

Is this what really happened historically?  I don't know.  Probably not.